# how to get meta[container?] information by java subprocess pid

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, containers

I have an output list of java threads `top -H -p [java ppid number]`

From Client I request DB and this creates new pid, which number I can see in output

I want to know - if there's a way to get info from this process, like User, what code it executes etc.. 
May be "Containers" can help? Like unpacking the container,servlet which process handles...

What's a strange question:
I'm admin. I have leaky pid, and want to know User and request it handles

Comment: It is unclear whether you are asking for information about the Java application's threads or its child processes.  Similarly, it is unclear whether you are talking about UNIX / Linux users, or something that the application understands ... which may be unrelated to UNIX / Linux user identities.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for application user who started thread

Comment: guess he can have some internal id

Comment: I exactly know that this pid was started by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get more information about Java threads using `jstack`, but there is not way to get the application user ... in the sense that you are asking.

If you want to do that, then the application itself would need to implement a way to record this and output it on request.